# Script Deployment Management Tool for NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

We are looking at removing developers from production and want a simple kind of deployment management tool. One suggestion that some members are using with SalesForce is **Jenkins**. I have never used Jenkins or any kind of deployment tool before. I normally just copied my code from IDE and updated the file in the SuiteScript file cabinet.

Does Jenkins work for NetSuite? Or what do you recommend for this purpose?

We are planning to use Bit Bucket (which runs Git in the background) as our version control in case that matters.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3):

IMO the greatest challenge in integrating with any CI environment(be it Jenkins or any other) is the fact that you can move code files from one system to another using code/APIs but, NOT things like scripts, custom records, fields its deployments , etc. for which you need a bundling process and hence, manual intervention.

NetSuite in recent Suiteworld 2015 said that its coming up "Change Management" which would allow you to put everything that is part of your app to version control system such as git. Please see SuiteAnswer Id 42387, when this feature is rolled out, you can integrate with your CI tool to automatically copy/deploy your app details to an another NetSuite account and run your tests there and accordingly pass/fail your build.

Comment: If you use bundling, will it pull the latest actual .js file out of the file cabinet in bundling? Just want to make sure. I do have other concerns running on bundling but I am just thinking through things at the moment

Comment: Yes it picks up latest files,  script, record,  be it any bundle component

Comment: what is `SuiteAnswer Id 42387` can you provide a link?

Comment: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42387  Note that you need to be logged into NetSuite. If this link does not work open any other SuiteAnswer by going through support tab and change the number at the end of url to 42387

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to remove developers from Production? This will severely hamper their ability to create solutions for your NetSuite account and will create a ton of overhead for them.

If you *must* have them out of Production, then probably your "best" option would be to have them build their solutions in Sandbox and then use SuiteBundles for deployment to Production. A Production Admin would need to update the appropriate Bundle(s) for all Production migrations.

NetSuite has also built a SuiteCloud IDE plugin for Eclipse which allows uploading and downloading files (no copy-paste necessary), so if you're not using that I would recommend it.

We are using Jenkins for our own internal automated testing, but not for deployment into NetSuite. I do not know if someone has already built a NetSuite plugin for Jenkins; it is likely you would have to build your own file upload mechanism using the NetSuite Web Services SOAP API, but that would still only allow deployment of source files. Developers will most likely also need to be creating and updating custom records, fields, lists as well as Script records and Script Deployment records, which you will not be able to do through Jenkins or any other tool that I know of.

Comment: We do have to have them out of production - long story. We do use the SuiteCloude IDE and I know it's abilities to run to an environment. I am thinking that the user who will do the actual deployments into production though we probably don't want trying to use an IDE, but rather a more simple method